# how to integrated the complex css website in phonegap..?

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

we had one web application build with complex CSS & business logic layer in Asp.net. Now as per requirement we want to build mobile application for same website using existing CSS & class file. The site is already mobile responsive, but we want to create hybrid mobile application with native look and feel. Hence we are looking for solution in phone-gap cross platform.

Comment: And whats your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ionic framework for PhoneGap.

[More about Ionic framework](https:///ionicframework.com/docs/)

Comment: I'm not sure introducing Angular in the project will help him, it would force to re-write a big part of the original site code, where i guess the goal of using phonegap/cordova is to try to keep the existing code the maximum possible